# AVAudioPlayer Interruption issue

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer, interrupt-handling

I have a problem with `AVAudioPlayer` Interruption.

And I'm not talking about the interruption during the incoming call. I can handle this situation very well. Call -> Interruption start -> End of call -> Interruption finish.

The problem is with the camera on the device. The situation is:

My player app is playing on background. I want to make a photo. I open the camera and make a photo. No interruption at all! But if I want to capture some video the interruption starts and the player becomes silent. At the same moment interruption finishes! (I have checked it on two devices with the help of `NSLog` - and I find it very weird) But the player doesn't continue playing the song because video camera is still ON. I close camera and NOW I expect the interruption to finish, but it was finished earlier and the player remain silent.

The question is: How to handle this situation?

Comment: found any solution to this? I am also facing similar issue.

Comment: Gave up using AVAudioPlayer. StreamingKit and AVPlayer are the ones I migrated to